# Getting related

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i having problem with this:

## model.py (1)

```
class Profession(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
    principal_area = models.ForeignKey(Area,verbose_name='Area principal',related_name='area_principal')
    others_areas = models.ManyToManyField(Area)
```

## model.py (2)

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)    
    activa = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In Model 1 i have a field "principal_area" and other "others_areas".

How ill list all professional where "principal_area" OR "others_areas" are in Area model from my views?

Sorry if im not too clear

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Django's [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Here is an example of how you could go about this:

```
area = Area.objects.get(**conditions)
Profession.objects.filter(
    Q(principal_area = area) | Q(others_areas__in = [area])
)
```

Comment: A great answer, though I'd also suggest to use OneToOneField instead of ForeignKey field for principal_area.